# How can I make the same request as this form with the request module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, request, multipartform-data

I want to make the same request as the html form below with request module.
But my code doesn't.
How can I make this request?

What I want to make :

```html
<form 
action="http://foo.com/upload.php" 
method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <input type="file" name="fileX">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

What I wrote :

```
const formData = {
  gamefile:{
      value:Buffer.from(datastr),
      options:{
          name:"fileX",
          filename:"foo.bar",
          contentType:"application/octet-stream"
      }
  }
}

const options = {
  url:"http://foo.com/upload.php",
  formData:formData,
  method:"post",
  headers:{
      "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
  }
} 

request(options,callback);
```

Comment: It seem good! Change `gamefile` to `file` (relate to `type="file"`)

Comment: thank you for answering, but It doesn't work ...

Comment: How do you check it is working or not?

Comment: send request. server works fine with html version. but server return "cannot receive file with " with js version (I can't know neither error detail nor server´s code).

Comment: I am sorry! Try change `gamefile` to `fileX`